# Inertia scroll on <ion-select interface="action-sheet"> for iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When using the `action-sheet` interface for an `ion-select` on Android there is inertial scrolling - a quick flick and you quickly scroll to the bottom of a long list. On iOS however, you can only scroll a few lines at a time making it tedious to scroll to the bottom of long lists.

Am I missing some parameter to enable inertial scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of Ionic `action-sheet` includes a fix for this on iOS, but it's only in Ionic4. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/action-sheet/action-sheet.scss

To enable inertial scrolling in an Ionic3 action-sheet, you need to add:
 `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the SCSS for the component.

Note: this will get overwritten if you do an `npm install` and overwrite Ionic src files.

In your project folder, go to: 
`node_modules/ionic-angular/components/action-sheet`

Open `action-sheet.scss` and either just add that 1 line to `.action-sheet-group`, or change the entire `.action-sheet-group` to the following (to match the Ionic4 version):

```
.action-sheet-group {
  flex-shrink: 2;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  pointer-events: all;

  background: var(--background);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

include this in global.scss

```
.action-sheet-group {
overflow: auto !important;
}
```